# Adding foreign key relationship with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, foreign-keys

This problem is similar to my previously asked question.  When I query data using the Entity Framework (EF) I always use the `MergeOption.NoTracking` option because I end up taking my EF generated objects and mapping them to view models which have lovely attributes decorated on the property to enforce validation and so on.

I am trying to add a foreign key relationship using the EF, but anytime I do I am getting the following exception:

`The object being attached to the source object is not attached to the same ObjectContext as the source object`

Here is my code:

```
    public static void UpdateDownloadFileVersion(DownloadFile downloadFile, int[] selectedVersions) {
        using (SupportEntity supportContext = new SupportEntity()) {
            supportContext.DownloadFiles.Attach(downloadFile);

            var productVersionIdsToAdd = (from v in selectedVersions
                                          where (downloadFile.ProductVersions.Any(pv => pv.Id == v) == false)
                                          select v).ToList();

            foreach (var productVersionId in productVersionIdsToAdd) {
                var productVersion = new ProductVersion() { Id = productVersionId };
                downloadFile.ProductVersions.Attach(productVersion); //Exception happens here.
                downloadFile.ProductVersions.Add(productVersion);
            }

            supportContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try something like this:                var productVersion = new ProductVersion() { Id = productVersionId };
                supportContext.ProductVersions.AttachTo("ProductVersions", productVersion);

Comment: @DmitrySavy - I think you meant `supportContext.AttachTo("ProductVersions", productVersion)`.  But, yes, that did the trick, though I really don't understand why.  How is `AttachTo` different from `ProductVersions.Attach`?  I also don't like this solution because the code isn't strongly typed now and a change could go unnoticed beyond compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where Stub Entities become very very useful...

```
var productVersion = new ProductVersion() { Id = productVersionId };  
supportContext.AttachTo("ProductVersions", productVersion);
```

Here is a good [article](http://www.palador.com/blog/post/Using-Stub-Entity-to-Add-Relationship.aspx)

In above case, when attached `productVersion` is assigned to `product versions`' entity, productversion entity gets attached to context, with `EntityState=Added`. Entire graph will be in or out of context.

Comment: Exactly this is the way todo it, don't try something else, it will break you're neck at some point!

Comment: @ntziolis - I already am using stub entities (see my posted code), but it didn't work (I was getting the exception).

Comment: @Dmitry Savy - I was using stub entities, but I was still getting an exception thrown.  Why do I need to call `AttachTo` with a string versus just called `ProductVersions.Attach`?